# Parsing Data as integer

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
var intVar = parseInt($(.span).data('1'));
alert(data)   // output Nan
</script>

---------------



      <span id ="span" class ="span" data-1="4" />
```

i want 'intVar'  as integer, but unable to parse 'data-1'

Comment: Please post the relevant markup and script.

Comment: Did you forget the quotes around ".span" ?

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/pp4j5/show))... provided that you

1.: don't alert `data` (since you didn't set it) and make sure your selector is a string...

```
alert(parseInt($('.span').data('1')));
```

2.: place your script *after* the dom node you're trying to access:

```
<span id="span" class="span" data-1="4" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(parseInt($('.span').data('1')));
</script>
```

3.: or wrap your code like so ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pp4j5/1/show/) and [reference](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)):

```html
...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            alert(parseInt($('.span').data('1')));
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="span" class="span" data-1="4" />
...
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var intVar = parseInt($('.span').data('1'));
alert(intVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do this  
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var intVar = parseInt($('.span').data('1'));
alert(intVar);

});
</script>



 <span id ="span" class ="span" data-1="4" />
```